# share image on facebook from android application

Tags: android, facebook

i'm developping an android application that allow user to share image on facebook.  But facebook only give you the permission if you have already submited a review. Or my application isn't complete and i want to test the share operation. how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all says it right here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

If you want to test it then you need to go to your app on the developers page of facebook, click on roles and add a tester.

Comment: thank you but why i can't be an admin and a tester in the same time ?

Comment: no i don't think so because when you choose an admin to be a developper or tester , the admin will be moved and not added. this is the error (You are trying to move all admins to a different role. You must have at least one admin)